# SVM equations from e1071 R package?

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am interested in test the SVM performance to classify several individuals into four groups/classes. When using the svmtrain LibSVM function from MATLAB, I am able to get the three equations used to classify those individuals among the 4 groups, based on the values of this equation. An scheme could be as follows:

```
                All individuals (N)*
                      |
 Group 1 (n1) <--- equation 1 --->  (N-n1)
                                      |
                   (N-n1-n2) <--- equation 2 ---> Group 2 (n2)
                      |
Group 3 (n3) <--- equation 3 ---> Group 4(n4)

*N = n1+n2+n3+n4
```

Is there any way to get these equations using the svm function in the e1071 R package?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`svm` in `e1071` uses the "one-against-one" strategy for multiclass classification (i.e. binary classification between all pairs, followed by voting). So to handle this hierarchical setup, you probably need to do a series of binary classifiers manually, like group 1 vs. all, then group 2 vs. whatever is left, etc.. Additionally, the basic `svm` function does not tune the hyperparameters, so you will typically want to use a wrapper like `tune` in `e1071`, or `train` in the excellent `caret` package.

Anyway, to classify new individuals in R, you don't have to plug numbers into an equation manually. Rather, you use the `predict` generic function, which has methods for different models like SVM. For model objects like this, you can also usually use the generic functions `plot` and `summary`. Here is an example of the basic idea using a linear SVM:

```
require(e1071)

# Subset the iris dataset to only 2 labels and 2 features
iris.part = subset(iris, Species != 'setosa')
iris.part$Species = factor(iris.part$Species)
iris.part = iris.part[, c(1,2,5)]

# Fit svm model
fit = svm(Species ~ ., data=iris.part, type='C-classification', kernel='linear')

# Make a plot of the model
dev.new(width=5, height=5)
plot(fit, iris.part)

# Tabulate actual labels vs. fitted labels
pred = predict(fit, iris.part)
table(Actual=iris.part$Species, Fitted=pred)

# Obtain feature weights
w = t(fit$coefs) %*% fit$SV

# Calculate decision values manually
iris.scaled = scale(iris.part[,-3], fit$x.scale[[1]], fit$x.scale[[2]]) 
t(w %*% t(as.matrix(iris.scaled))) - fit$rho

# Should equal...
fit$decision.values
```

[image]

Tabulate actual class labels vs. model predictions:

```
> table(Actual=iris.part$Species, Fitted=pred)
            Fitted
Actual       versicolor virginica
  versicolor         38        12
  virginica          15        35
```

Extract feature weights from `svm` model object (for feature selection, etc.). Here, `Sepal.Length` is obviously more useful.

```
> t(fit$coefs) %*% fit$SV
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
[1,]    -1.060146  -0.2664518
```

To understand where the decision values come from, we can calculate them manually as the dot product of the feature weights and the preprocessed feature vectors, minus the intercept offset `rho`. (Preprocessed means possibly centered/scaled and/or kernel transformed if using RBF SVM, etc.)

```
> t(w %*% t(as.matrix(iris.scaled))) - fit$rho
         [,1]
51 -1.3997066
52 -0.4402254
53 -1.1596819
54  1.7199970
55 -0.2796942
56  0.9996141
...
```

This should equal what is calculated internally:

```
> head(fit$decision.values)
   versicolor/virginica
51           -1.3997066
52           -0.4402254
53           -1.1596819
54            1.7199970
55           -0.2796942
56            0.9996141
...
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, John. The reason because I want to know these equations is to assess which parameters from the total have more importance when classifying my events.

Comment: @ManuelRamón Ahh gotcha. Those are called the "weights" for a linear SVM. See edit above for how to calculate from an svm model object. Good luck!

Comment: Your example has only two categories (versicolor and virginica) and you got a vector with two coeffcients, one for each variable used to classify the iris data. If I have N categories I get N-1 vectors from `with(fit, t(coefs) %*% SV)`. What is the meaning of each vector?

Comment: The length of the weights vector will be equal to the number of features that were *actually used* to fit the SVM. If you used the formula interface and factor features, your input features get processed into numeric dummy variables via `model.matrix()`. Thus, if you have a factor feature with 3 levels, it will get processed into only two final features. That is probably where your N-1 is coming from.

Comment: I understand why I get N-1 vectors of weights, but I don´t understand how they are used. If you run the SVM classification with the iris data considering the three species you get two vectors. Is the first one use to differenciate between the versicolor and the other species? Or between virginica and the others?

Comment: Ohh I see...you decided to go with the multi-class mode up front. I see what you're saying - if running on the full `iris` data, `coefs` only has two columns, where I would have expected 3. `rho` has 3 values and `decision.values` has 3 columns as well (for the 3 one vs. one binary classifiers). See above for how to calculate the decision values manually, but so far I can't reproduce what is stored in `decision.values` from any combination of those 2 `coefs` sets and 3 `rho` values. I'm stumped here at the moment...

Comment: What do the signs mean? Is it like negative weights support one class and positive weights support another class?